# What is wrong with my call to Node's readFile method in an electron renderer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, electron-forge

I've created a minimal reproduction app which demonstrates my issue based on the "typescript + webpack" [template for electron-forge](https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template). I have made a few changes in order to demonstrate my issue and you can [find the entire app here](https://github.com/taylorthurlow/electron-problem-min-repro). The README contains all necessary reproduction instructions (dead simple).

Basically what I've done is create a `src/other.html` file, and my goal is to load the contents of this file and replace the `#main-content` div's contents (located in `src/index.html`) with the new contents. The code to do this is located in `src/renderer.ts` but here is the code in question:

```js
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

const contentElement = document.getElementById("main-content");
const linkElement = document.getElementById("switch");

if (!contentElement) throw "Unable to find main content div.";
if (!linkElement) throw "Unable to find link element.";

linkElement?.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const href = linkElement.getAttribute("href");

  if (href) {
    const fullPath = path.join(__dirname, href);

    console.log(`Full path: ${fullPath}`);

    fs.readFile(fullPath, (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      // show the selected page
      contentElement.innerHTML = "";
      contentElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", data.toString());
    });
  }
});
```

It adds a click handler which grabs the href attribute value and attempts to construct the new file's path with `__dirname`, given that the two HTML files are in the same directory.

Instead of this code working as expected I encounter the following error in the dev console:

[image: dev console error]

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid package /Users/taylorthurlow/Temp/electron-problem-min-repro/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar
    at createError (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5)
    at Object.e.readFile (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (renderer.ts:50)
createError @ electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5
e.readFile @ electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5
(anonymous) @ renderer.ts:50
```

The console log call prints:

```
Full path: /Users/taylorthurlow/Temp/electron-problem-min-repro/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/renderer/other.html
```

I took a look at the `Resources` directory that `electron.asar` is expected to be inside of, but I only see `default_app.asar` and some other unrelated stuff. I assume this is why I'm getting the error. I don't understand enough about javascript/typescript or any of the ecosystem surrounding it to really understand what's going on here.

Some version numbers:

- `electron-forge` v6 beta 54
- `electron` 11.0.3
- `node` 12.20.0

Comment: @StackSlave that would be typescript's [safe navigation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator#TypeScript). Not actually necessary in this instance as I throw an error if it's not present already.